# Hokuyo Laser Installation ubuntu

Tags: ros, laser, installation, hokuyo, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

I installed the ROS software on my Ubuntu system properly and ran most of the tutorials to check if I have installed correctly and it did.

I then tried to connect my hokuyo urg 04lx 2d sensor to the desktop and referred to the supported sensor page . However I am unable to download the hokuyo node repository. Can anyone tell me how to do it.

PS : I am a complete newbie to linux operating systems , so a detailed command line explanation will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ankit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35022/hokuyo-laser-installation-ubuntu/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hokuyo node is a complete black-box driver, it shoulder work if you've downloaded it properly from [laser_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_drivers). If you're a 'complete newbie' it's fairly likely you did that wrong. Go to the terminal, copy this in line by line (if you followed setup instructions verbatim).

```
cd ~/ros_workspace
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/laser_drivers/trunk laser_driver
cd laser_driver
rosmake
roslaunch hokuyo_node hokuyo_test.launch
```

and it should launch and spurt out your info on topic /scan

---

Originally posted by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) with karma: 215 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-09-27**:
Thank you that solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest using the prebuilt packages for the Hokuyo sensors. Assuming you're using ROS Fuerte:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers
roslaunch hokuyo_node hokuyo_test.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2012-08-16**:
[ WARN] [1345162041.644055224]: The use_rep_117 parameter has not been set or is set to false.  Please see: http://ros.org/wiki/rep_117/migration
[ERROR] [1345162041.655830925]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
Failed to open port: /dev/ttyACM0. Permission denied (errno = 13). You probably don